# Select Random Datas From File

Tags: c#, file-io, random

I'm learning C# and now I need to build a home project(just to learn how to use file I/O and random). I have a file(names.txt) like this:

```
Nathan
John
Max
Someone
```

But how I can access this file(already know) and select a random name, print it and delete this name from the file? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Tests.Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = "c:\\toto.txt";
            var content = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList();
            var selected = content[new Random().Next(0, content.Count)];

            Debug.Write(selected);

            content.Remove(selected);
            File.WriteAllLines(fileName, content.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you definitely need to delete the name from the file? Or can you just delete it from a list in memory?

Anyway, I would separate out the tasks this way:

- Load the text from the file e.g. with `File.ReadAllLines`
- Convert to a `List<string>` which will let you remove an element
- Create a new instance of `System.Random`
- Pick a random element using `Random.Next()`
- Fetch (and remove) the name from the list
- Print the name
- Write the file back with `File.WriteAllLines`

Now that you know the steps involved, have a go at each of them - and if you get stuck, ask for more details about a specific problem.

Comment: I need to delete it from the file, sorry :(, but thanks for your very good answer!

Comment: Momentary confusion struck me when I saw the name and the rep - "Who's this Tony the Pony, how did they get 111K rep without me ever seeing them answer a question?" - then I checked the profile and all confusion dissipated :)

Comment: @Russ I see his profile and as I can see he is Jon Skeet, the blog link is to Jon Skeet's blog.